# pdf objects won't display in IE but will in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf

I am at my wits end.

The following code displays a pdf to the user based on a query string and pulls the pdf from a file server. It works great in google chrome. However, I need this to work in IE as well.

When I use IE, it just shows a blank space where the pdf should be. Below is my aspx and C# file. Both browsers have adobe reader addons installed.

**FRONT END:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="JobBookViewer.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Job Book Viewer</title>
    <style type="text/css">       
        #form1 {
            font-weight: 700;
            width: 118px;
            height: 217px;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetPDFwindow()
        {
            var varclientscreenwidth = screen.width;
            var varclientscreenheight = screen.height;
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body onload="SetPDFwindow()">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="width: 203px; z-index: 1; left: 7px; top: 4px; position: relative; height: 34px; right: 811px;">
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAbout" runat="server" BackColor="#B0F1FF" style="z-index: 1; left: 873px; top: 1px; position: absolute" Text="About"     OnClick="ButtonAbout_Click" Visible="false" />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 735px; top: 41px; position: absolute; width: 206px; height: 447px;"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack =" true"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
        <div id="chromecheck" runat="server" visible="false">
                          Chrome
        </div>
         <div id="iecheck" runat="server" visible="false">
                        We have detected that you are not using Chrome. If the program is not working, please switch to Chrome
        </div>
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64
    , <%= this.file %>" type="application/pdf" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: -3px; top: 1px; height: 210%; width: 612%; margin-top: 1px;" id="myPDF"></object>

        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace JobBookViewer
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public String file;
        public String id;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser;
            browser = Request.Browser;
            if (browser.Browser.ToLower().Equals("chrome"))
            {
                chromecheck.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                iecheck.Visible = true;
            }
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // myPDF.Style.Add("width", (Convert.ToInt32(clientScreenWidth.Value)-200).ToString());
                file = fnFilePDFName(@"\\spfs1\stone\Long Term Share\db_objects\JobBookViewer\select_mold.pdf");

                try
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Request.QueryString["MoldID"]))  // if the string is not null
                    {
                        id = (Page.Request.QueryString["MoldID"]);
                        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
                        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dinfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"\\spfs1\stone\mold_books\" + id.ToString());
                        System.IO.FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
                        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in Files)
                        {
                            ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           file = fnFilePDFName(@"\\spfs1\stone\mold_books\" + Page.Request.QueryString["MoldID"] + @"\" + ListBox1.SelectedValue);
        }

        private string ModifyQueryStringValue(string p_Name, string p_NewValue)
        {
            var nameValues = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
            nameValues.Set(p_Name, p_NewValue);
            string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            string updatedQueryString = "?" + nameValues.ToString();
            return url + updatedQueryString;
        }

        public string fnFilePDFName(string path)
        {
            string sfileContent;
            Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            sfileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return sfileContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be some whitespace in the uri which should not be there

Comment: Do you have Acrobat Reader or some other type of reader? IE does not handle pdf itself and needs a plugin to show pdf content.

Comment: Is your browser 64-bit and the adobe pdf plugin 32-bit by any chance? I would start troubleshooting by removing all of the extra's you have in the style and data attributes. Just `<object data="file.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>` should be enough. If even that doesn't work most likely your plugin isn't installed correctly.

Comment: The plugin appears to be 32 and 64 bit architecture.

Comment: the following is a resulting html file. Strangly, this html file has the same behavior as my application. see the following link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-umo7G978pdalJrdVhibHU4Y0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#search=data%20uri. IE does not support data uti for pdf

Comment: If it were up to me, I wouldn't. However I have to make this work somehow.